# OOM error with data upload from MySQL table into Apache Druid using JSON task

Tags: druid, data-ingestion, apache-druid

A digital ocean droplet was spinned off to run **Apache Druid(v28.0.1)** with **8 GB** of RAM.
Installed MySQL database and created a table with 11 columns (datatype-varchar and most of the fields are nullable).
Have imported 4.8 million records in it the same table.

I wanted to import data (**all 4.8 million rows**) into the Druid by submitting a JSON task but that returns out of memory error.

However it works when I try use the same JSON task to upload only **30 thousand rows** (which brings an alternative for me to submit json task 160 times to upload all the 48 lac records but there should be a better way).

My assumption is that these issues occurs due to the memory parameters defined in the start-druid script present in the bin dir.
Or do I need to change something in the submitted JSON task itself?

What exactly should I change in the configuration?

Following is the JSON task that I submitted

```
{
  "type": "index_parallel",
  "spec": {
    "dataSchema": {
      "dataSource": "mydata_sql",
      "timestampSpec": {
        "column": "__time",
        "format": "iso",
        "missingValue": "2024-02-18T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "dimensionsSpec": {
        "dimensions": [],
        "dimensionExclusions": [
          "__time"
        ],
        "includeAllDimensions": false,
        "useSchemaDiscovery": false
      },
      "metricsSpec": [],
      "granularitySpec": {
        "type": "uniform",
        "segmentGranularity": "DAY",
        "queryGranularity": {
          "type": "none"
        },
        "rollup": false,
        "intervals": []
      },
      "transformSpec": {
        "filter": null,
        "transforms": []
      }
    },
    "ioConfig": {
      "type": "index_parallel",
      "inputSource": {
        "type": "sql",
        "sqls": [
          "SELECT * FROM mydatatable"
        ],
        "foldCase": false,
        "database": {
          "type": "mysql",
          "connectorConfig": {
            "createTables": true,
            "host": "localhost",
            "port": 1527,
            "connectURI": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb",
            "user": "mydbuser",
            "password": "mydbpass",
            "dbcp": null
          },
          "driverClassName": null
        }
      },
      "inputFormat": null,
      "appendToExisting": false,
      "dropExisting": false
    },
    "tuningConfig": {
      "type": "index_parallel",
      "maxRowsPerSegment": null,
      "appendableIndexSpec": {
        "type": "onheap",
        "preserveExistingMetrics": false
      },
      "maxRowsInMemory": 1000000,
      "maxBytesInMemory": 0,
      "skipBytesInMemoryOverheadCheck": false,
      "maxTotalRows": null,
      "numShards": null,
      "splitHintSpec": null,
      "partitionsSpec": null,
      "indexSpec": {
        "bitmap": {
          "type": "roaring"
        },
        "dimensionCompression": "lz4",
        "stringDictionaryEncoding": {
          "type": "utf8"
        },
        "metricCompression": "lz4",
        "longEncoding": "longs"
      },
      "indexSpecForIntermediatePersists": {
        "bitmap": {
          "type": "roaring"
        },
        "dimensionCompression": "lz4",
        "stringDictionaryEncoding": {
          "type": "utf8"
        },
        "metricCompression": "lz4",
        "longEncoding": "longs"
      },
      "maxPendingPersists": 0,
      "forceGuaranteedRollup": false,
      "reportParseExceptions": false,
      "pushTimeout": 0,
      "segmentWriteOutMediumFactory": null,
      "maxNumConcurrentSubTasks": 1,
      "maxRetry": 3,
      "taskStatusCheckPeriodMs": 1000,
      "chatHandlerTimeout": "PT10S",
      "chatHandlerNumRetries": 5,
      "maxNumSegmentsToMerge": 100,
      "totalNumMergeTasks": 10,
      "logParseExceptions": false,
      "maxParseExceptions": 2147483647,
      "maxSavedParseExceptions": 0,
      "maxColumnsToMerge": -1,
      "awaitSegmentAvailabilityTimeoutMillis": 0,
      "maxAllowedLockCount": -1,
      "partitionDimensions": []
    }
  },
  "context": {
    "forceTimeChunkLock": true,
    "useLineageBasedSegmentAllocation": true
  }
}
```